# Should not the users be suggested if not required to set the version in tags?

Tags: discussion

More often than not I have seen questions(with their answers) which will very much vary per drupal version. It would be very helpful if every question was tagged by the Drupal version, may be single or multiple.

Even if its not made required, would it not be better if users were suggested to add a version when submitting their question? I think users can take a cue from that, for adding it.

What does the community say?

Comment: Have a read of http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/703/what-is-the-rationale-behind-this-instruction-in-the-7-tag-wiki and the links in the answers...we've been here before ;)

Answer (score 2):

Version tags should be used only when the question is specific for a Drupal version, as they don't mean "I am using Drupal X." To make a comparison with a programming language, using [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7) for a question that is valid for Drupal 5 and Drupal 6 too is like using [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#-4.0) for a question about the `if` control statement in C#, which didn't change in C# 4.

Using a version tag, you are saying to the users who read the question that it doesn't interest them if the are using a previous version.
There is also a problem with a tag used with most of the questions as that tag would stop to be useful. Imagine having [drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) as tag: Since it would be used on every question, it would not classify any question, which is the purpose of tags.

If the user doesn't say which Drupal version is using, the answers could answer for both the current version, and the previous version. This is preferable, and it would avoid the same question is once asked for a Drupal version, and then for another Drupal version.

Last, the Drupal version can be given in the question text.